# How to do clean up job for sql dependency when database hosted in shared location

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldependency

our database hosted in share location of ORCSWEB. so i do not have permission to execute this below script

```
KILL QUERY NOTIFICATION SUBSCRIPTION 26
```

ORCSWEB said they will not allow us to get right permission to execute above script because they think that is security issue for their database.

i try to run the below script to clean up sql dependency related dump data from my c# program but not 100% successfull.

### this below is running fine to clear conversation sys table

```
DECLARE @ConvHandle uniqueidentifier
DECLARE Conv CURSOR FOR
SELECT CEP.conversation_handle FROM sys.conversation_endpoints CEP
WHERE CEP.state = 'DI' or CEP.state = 'CD'
OPEN Conv;
FETCH NEXT FROM Conv INTO @ConvHandle;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) BEGIN
    END CONVERSATION @ConvHandle WITH CLEANUP;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Conv INTO @ConvHandle;
END
CLOSE Conv;
DEALLOCATE Conv;
```

my full routine which used and stuck for permission.

```
private void ClearOldSubscriptions()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            string sql =
                ////@"DECLARE @UniqueTimeout AS int = 3586; " +
                @"DECLARE @SubscriptionId AS int; " +
                @"DECLARE @Sql AS varchar(max); " +
                @"DECLARE SubscriptionCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD " +
                @"    FOR " +
                @"        SELECT id " +
                @"        FROM sys.dm_qn_subscriptions " +
                @"      WHERE database_id = DB_ID() " +
                @"            AND timeout = @UniqueTimeout " +
                @"OPEN SubscriptionCursor; " +
                @"FETCH NEXT FROM SubscriptionCursor INTO @SubscriptionId; " +
                @"WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 " +
                @"BEGIN " +
                @"    SET @Sql = 'KILL QUERY NOTIFICATION SUBSCRIPTION ' + CONVERT(varchar, @SubscriptionId); " +
                @"    EXEC(@Sql); " +
                @" " +
                @"    FETCH NEXT FROM SubscriptionCursor INTO @SubscriptionId; " +
                @"END";

            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.Parameters.Add("@UniqueTimeout", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 432000;

            connection.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

private void ClearNotificationQueue()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            string sql =
                @"DECLARE @Conversation AS uniqueidentifier; " +
                @"DECLARE ConversationCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD  " +
                @"    FOR " +
                @"        SELECT CEP.conversation_handle FROM sys.conversation_endpoints CEP  " +
                @"        WHERE CEP.state = 'DI' or CEP.state = 'CD' " +
                @"     " +
                @"OPEN ConversationCursor; " +
                @"FETCH NEXT FROM ConversationCursor INTO @Conversation; " +
                @"WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  " +
                @"BEGIN " +
                @"    END CONVERSATION @Conversation WITH CLEANUP; " +
                @" " +
                @"    FETCH NEXT FROM ConversationCursor INTO @Conversation; " +
                @"END " +
                @"";

            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = sql;

            connection.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i like to know who will clear old subscription from this system table `sys.dm_qn_subscriptions`

Comment: Well, we can't do it. You need to clear this up with the people who manage your server.